GenAI is now commonly used for coding (e.g., 25% of the new Google codebase). Could the 2-year-old ban on using genAI for coding be lifted?
I read:


Google CEO says a quarter of the company’s new code is already AI generated.
According to Stack Overflow’s 2024 Developer Survey, over 75 percent of respondents are already using or are “planning to use” AI tools to assist with software development.
Another survey by GitHub indicated that 92 percent of US-based developers are currently using AI coding tools.


Based on this overwhelming use of genAI for coding, could the 2-year-old ban on using genAI for coding in SO answers be lifted? The ban was established when LLMs were much weaker (e.g., ~230 fewer elos on this benchmark) and when humans were less acquainted with LLMs.

Google’s share prices have spiked since their “AI gamble”. They will no doubt be keen for that price to keep rising, hence statements like that. Take what they say with a few healthy pinches of salt; ask yourself how much of that code was likely to have been accepted into the codebase without extensive human review, for example

Please read up on the echo-chamber effect of reinforced bad practices that this change could cause. Google's behavior should not dictate how this site operates, but rather common sense and good data should.

If someone wants LLM generated vomit, they can go to an LLM and ask it for vomit. The reason users come to [so] is because the content isn't vomitted out by an LLM. Quality is the important thing to the community here, and we ensure that with human beings answering and validating the content posted here.

Btw, the ban is not (only) about coding in SO answers, but about writing answers with LLMs. Given that we still find users copy-pasting LLM content into SO answers, mostly without checking and on high volume, I'd say that the ban is still valid.

@ThomA "According to Stack Overflow’s 2024 Developer Survey, over 75 percent of respondents are already using or are “planning to use” AI tools to assist with software development." so I guess some SO users are ok to use LLMs?

@BDL how about lifting the ban for code?

@Clive  ask yourself how much of the human-written code was likely to have been accepted into the codebase without extensive human review, for example?

@HovercraftFullOfEels Google is one of the 3 stats I gave. Can give more.

But that’s just arguing that you should because you can (debatable how true “can” is, but that’s your argument). Doesn’t seem strong. What are you fixing or improving?

@Clive " What are you fixing or improving?" what do you mean?

Exactly that - By allowing AI-generated content what is improved or fixed on Stack Overflow vs the current order?

@Clive improved use of human time

Doubt it, people will just have to be more on their guard when reviewing. Robbing Peter to pay Paul, as it were

I didn't say that users didn't want to use LLMs, @FranckDernoncourt, I said that users didn't want LLM vomit when they are looking for solutions to a problem on [so]. A user is welcome to ask a LLM their question prior to browsing or asking on [so], and seeing in the vomit it gives them does something they want, but if it doesn't or if the LLM is unable to give them vomit they understand, then they may well want to ask here, where human being will actually provide content that the author themselves understands.

As long as I am alive, I will be against GenAI content and will never find said content helpful if it's used to answer my Stack Overflow questions. I have spent hours trying to get GenAI to output what I want, and while tedious, I was able to do it myself in half that time.  So unless the quality of the responses increase by a several hundred factors, I don't see GenAI being helpful, anytime soon.

I will flag and downvote any contribution, where I have a high confidence, was generated by a LLM.  I don't care who submitted it. I have spent hours and days verifying and reporting hundreds of answers submitted by an author, due to a single confirmation, of a LLM answer by that author. Users who want to use LLM to submit answers, make me suspicious of their content, suspicious enough that I often will verify their contributions.

The logic of your second bullet does not follow. I am using AI tools to assist with software development, but I will never ever post an AI-generated answer to StackOverflow and I am a strong supporter of the ban, for the reasons illustrated in the answer. Also see my answer to a related question.

I really don't get why this pops up time after time. If you want to use AI, use it then. Nobody stops you from using it directly. Why do you want to force it onto Stack Overflow? Why should people use SO to get their AI generated answers, when they can just ask the AI directly?

Please don't lift the ban. It would be pointless and harmful, as it already has proven to be. The fact that lots of programmers use AI has no relevance to its ban for answering questions.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I think the fact that lots of programmers use AI to write code has relevance to its ban for answering questions, since some of  them use SO.

It does not. Experts should answer questions, if you have to use an AI to help you answer a question then you shouldn't be answering it.

@Lino "Why should people use SO to get their AI generated answers, when they can just ask the AI directly?" because on SO, posts would  be checked+ possibly improved by humans.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk "if you have to use an AI to help you answer a question then you shouldn't be answering it" disagreed. Why code from scratch if some LLM can draft most of the code?

@FranckDernoncourt I don’t see why anyone who has the expertise to check+improve an AI answer wouldn’t simply post one themselves.

"Based on this overwhelming use of genAI for coding" - absolutely not, because none of this has absolutely anything whatsoever to do for the reasoning behind the ban. And you know this; you were in that discussion, and in fact extensive discussion all over MSO and MSE about AI is the only reason I recognize your name.

@blackgreen Same reason as why 25% of the new Google codebase is created by genAI even googlers could write it:  save time.

@KarlKnechtel at time of the ban, genAI wasn't as good. Overwhelming use of genAI for coding shows that now it works decently.

@FranckDernoncourt People use it is not the same as it's good.

@Starship likely some correlation

@FranckDernoncourt People smoke. Is smoking good for you?

@Starship they keep smoking due to nicotine. What's the LLM nicotine?

@FranckDernoncourt At one point they had never smoked before and decided to start...

@Starship If 25% of the new Google codebase, we're talking about returning users.

I generally consider such claims more of an admittance that the business cares more about printing money than producing a valuable product. That's not to say businesses shouldn't be focused on making money, more, i don't feel 25% of google's code base supposedly being AI generated is necessarily a relevant argument in favor of allowing AIGen answers. What value would such answers bring here, when one could instead just ask AIGen and get a more recent iteration of an AIGenned answer, potentially based on a larger or better focused data set than was available when the old answer was generated?

If generative ai is a revolution in the making... surely it wouldn't benefit from cataloging older versions of its answers on SO rather than having people generate new answers every time.

@KevinB software don't always use the latest lib versions. And again, point of SO is having human check/improve the answer.

@FranckDernoncourt would an ai not be able to generate answers with older lib versions? if not... then what are we doing?

@KevinB we're not at that level yet. point of SO is having human check/improve the answer.

but why? that's a waste of time. just generate again

@KevinB generated answers aren't always perfect.  Point of SO is having human check/improve the generated answers.

@FranckDernoncourt historically (evidenced by the influx of non-checked/improved wrong ai answers we received) humans don't do that on average. Do you have an army of subject matter experts willing to slog through ai generated content for mistakes and correct them?

@KevinB then only allow genAI for people with >10k rep?

10k is both easy and hard to attain. rep whores will answer all the easy newbie questions and jump on all the bounties to rush to that arbitrary limit, while domain experts spend an hour on a decent answer to a decent question, which comes along once in a blue moon, and get a few updoots out of it. -- the ban is about having rules in place that unequivocally allow the hammer to come down on anyone who copypastes out of chatgpt, anyone who hasn't got a clue but still "answers" the question by having chatgpt answer it for them. curation/moderation efforts are costly. we do not want junk here.

@ChristophRackwitz no,  the ban is about avoiding a flood a LLM answers. A min rep threshold would avoid that.

what are you proposing? to allow 10k rep users the posting of ChatGPT answers? nobody wants that from anyone at any rep. I think the feedback you got so far is very clear. I won't tell you to accept it. that's up to you. I will tell you, I will not spend time trying to convince anyone who can't be convinced.

@ChristophRackwitz Yes, I propose to allow 10k rep users to post answers that used some LLMs.

that opens the door for crafty people that will, or already do, use AI to generate a bunch of question-answer pairs for which the LLM came up with the answer and the human merely made the machine rephrase the text so it doesn't reek of ChatGPT's style. that's equivalent to someone googling on a topic they have no clue of, then writing an answer. that is terrible. "legalization" is strategically a bad move. I'd rather they keep the policy, and anyone who feels like having an LLM assist them had better make damn sure it's not a substitute for their own competence.

if this policy changes, a lot of real humans will leave, because this site would become nothing more than a frontend to ChatGPT, and the "people" posting answers will be sockpuppets of ChatGPT. there is no joy in any of that. I have no desire to spend my time in a community of copywriters. anyone who wants to, can start a new site. the people who give this site its life do not want any part of that. if you do, this place is not for you.

@ChristophRackwitz most such questions would be closed as duplicates, likely causing a question ban, and there's a limit of 50 questions per month. Humans are already progressively visiting SO less frequently because GPT and other LLMs have become pretty good.

I've seen users mine github issues for Q&A pairs they can post. it's disingenious.

@ChristophRackwitz they could do that without using any LLMs. If rep whoring is the issue, the remove rep as maths SE did?

NO

Even assuming that Google's CEO has an accurate picture of who and how writes their gargantuan code base, what they do is not our concern.

Using AI to assist with software development is not the same as presenting solutions to other people's questions as if you were a subject-matter expert.


The main issues with AI posts (answers in particular) which prompted the ban all remain:

No matter how good a GenAI model is, they can still hallucinate. There's even research that suggests AI models may never not hallucinate. The burden of vetting such content that looks good on the surface but may be fundamentally flawed then falls on the shoulders of an already strained community.
GenAI content can be produced at a much faster rate than what the community is able to curate/moderate
Even for vetted content, moderators (but anyone except the poster really) are unable to verify claims that the content was actually vetted beforehand. It'd come down to hunches and subjective bias. That kind of moderation is prone to be unfair and ineffective.
plagiarism: after having handled thousands of AI flags on this site, I can tell you that almost nobody gives proper credit to the AI. Folks tend to present the content as their own, thus misrepresenting someone else's work.
The only value proposition that Stack Overflow still has over an LLM is that there's the expectation that a human being has authored the text as written.
Allowing for an exception this big to the AI ban would open the floodgates.

There is a case to be made about using AI to improve a post's grammar, formatting, etc. but that suffers from the same issues as point #3.
I really don't see how we could realistically allow AI content in almost any form while staying true to Stack Overflow's values and a Community made of humans at its core.

"No matter how good a GenAI model is, they can still hallucinate." just like humans. " I can tell you that almost nobody gives proper credit to the AI." it's banned, so giving proper credit to the AI = "please ban me".

@FranckDernoncourt Even when it wasn't banned no one gave proper credit.

Few people will be willing to admit they have no idea what they're doing and just let an AI do it for them.

@FranckDernoncourt When humans hallucinate, it's usually more obviously wrong, and even when it isn't they can't output realistic-looking nonsense at nearly the same rate that AI can so either way it's much less of a curation/moderation burden (I notice you didn't address any of blackgreen's points about that).

@JohnMontgomery I agree with blackgreen's point ("GenAI content can be produced at a much faster rate than what the community is able to curate/moderate") about that. But there could be way to address it, eg demand min rate and thresholding post/hour.

But why bother putting in extra systems for something which delivers no value? “I can expend less effort” doesn’t seem reasonable - if you don’t have the time/will, then don’t do it, leave it for those that do. Unless I’m missing something, that’s the only argument you’re making for this change?

@Clive Yes, that’s the main argument I am making for this change. (imho, a strong one). Another argument is accessibility (e.g., some people can't type much due to medical condition).

I’ve never heard (until now) anyone saying that they would contribute more/better to Stack Overflow if they only had to spend less effort. That seems like the opposite of what we want to encourage.

re: "the only value proposition". I like to think we have more than that over LLMs :/

that NO can't be emphasized enough. if anyone wants to turn it into a granite monument that can be seen from orbit, I'd give a few bucks for the cause... and thank you for having the patience to list all the reasons why.
